# Why had my rendering stopped working?

Tags: rendering

It was working fine until I got into making the plane look glossy, then it just stopped showing any changes as I made them. I tried working on the shape and made it into glass and it morphed a little in the rendering but does not look like its supposed too. I am using a Mac computer OSX 10.6.8. I just got this program tonight and am studying the lessons trying to learn it!

[image: See where Im at in pic here]

Comment: what are your computer specs ? maybe the memory has run out

Comment: I have 2 GB of memory and the activity monitor says Im using 1.78, so I have not run out.. could that be the issue that I dont have enough left?

Comment: MAYBE , but i would probably get more memory or get rid of some stuff

Comment: Any other suggestions for why the rendering is not fully working? It will show the change in color but it wont show the full properties of glass or glossy, etc, I freed up some memory on my computer but it still looks like the pic above. I really want to learn this so please help! :)

Comment: Is that actually the material applied to the plane? You may need to upload your .blend file to Pasteall.org so we can take a look at it . . .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your plane has multiple materials on it but out of sight :
[image]
Your changes on this material are not visible because it's not assigned to your object (plane).
Remove the other materials or affect this one to your geometry :
1. Select your plane, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go in edit mode, then <kbd>A</kbd> to select All
2. Select the checker material from the material list
3. Click the *Assign* button

[image]